# Download progress event is not working in ios using cordova plugin file transfer

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, file-transfer

I am using cordova file transfer plugin to download files from my app.

But, when I m using progress event to show the user to progress bar on downloading It is not working properly every time it shows 0%.

Here is code which I used to show progress event....

```
$cordovaFileTransfer.download(url, targetPath, downloadOptions,
    trustHosts).then(function(result) {
}, function(err) {
}, function(progress) {
    if (progress.lengthComputable) {
        $rootScope.downloadProgress = (progress.loaded / progress.total) * 100;
    } else {
        $rootScope.downloadProgress = (progress.loaded / file_size) * 100;
    }
});
```

Can anyone please help me out to solve this downloading progress bar issue in ios.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem six months ago, it seems to be a bug in the Filetransfer plugin.

The solution I found was to do the changes mentioned here:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9936

> In CDVFileTransfer.m, download() method between line 447 to 462
>
> ```
> delegate.connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:delegate startImmediately:NO];
>
> if (self.queue == nil) {
>     self.queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
> }
>
> [delegate.connection setDelegateQueue:self.queue];
>
> @synchronized (activeTransfers) {
>     activeTransfers[delegate.objectId] = delegate;
> }
>
> // Downloads can take time
> // sending this to a new thread calling the download_async method
> dispatch_async(
>     dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, (unsigned long)NULL),
>     ^(void) { [delegate.connection start];}
>     );
> ```
>
> If I replaced it with the older version of the code, then it works.
>
> ```
> delegate.connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:delegate];
> if (activeTransfers == nil) {
>     activeTransfers = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
> }
> [activeTransfers setObject:delegate forKey:delegate.objectId];
> ```

Comment: [Answers should contain more than just a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).
Please include all essential information in the answer, and provide links for reference only.

Comment: I think this solution will only work after the *.ipa is generated in the build proccess. But what about testing it with Phonegap Developer app, for example? We don't get the fix. So we can't test it before building the app. Am I right or is there a way to make this fix work while just serving the app and previewing it on the Phonegap Developer app/emulator?

Comment: Fran, how did you actually applied the solution described on that link? I followed the instructions there to change the code within the download() method, but still couldn't make it work in XCode's iPhone emulator. Like @Meyer said, could you please edit your answer with an example code so that we can try to do the same as you did? Maybe it will fix the problem for us, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
function (progress) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        $scope.downloadProgress = (progress.loaded / progress.total) * 100;
                        console.log($scope.downloadProgress)
                    });
                }
```

> Replace your progress function with this function, u can check your result in console